# Cut String in parts

Tags: java, string

I'm getting from JSON string like this:

```
{
  "name":"Google"
  "items": "item1,item2,item3,item4"
}
```

So I want to create array `String[] items` and populate it with items from this string. I need somehow to cut this string in parts. Also I'm getting different number of items, not only 4, like in example.

How can I do this....?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Shows us the whole JSON string !

Comment: In general, try to google this very basic stuff first. Chances are very, very low that no one before you tried to split a string and posted it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for the below line or I misunderstood your question  ?

```
String[] result = yourString.split(",");
```

Comment: Yes that is my answer... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] items = incomingString.split(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at `String.split()` you can pass in a `char` that will split up your `string` and return an `array`